# Create Widget Using Page Builder In Magento2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I already created a widget and it's working fine.
But there is no option to add widgets using page builder.
What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. The simplest is using the Text content type to include the widget using the standard TinyMCE widget feature.

Your other option is to create a new content type that wraps your widget in a Page Builder content type. Our Products content type does exactly this, it's just an interface for the Catalog Product List widget.

products.xml contains a mass converter to create the widget directive:

> view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/products.xml

```
<converters>
    <converter component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/products/mass-converter/widget-directive" name="widget_directive">
        <config>
            <item name="html_variable" value="html"/>
        </config>
    </converter>
</converters>
```

You can refer to the detailed answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275024/create-widget-content-in-page-builder).